# Estimating the historical drift and volatility

Tags: volatility

I want to forecast prices $S(t)$ of some asset based on historical daily values. I want to use the geometric Brownian motion given by an SDE:
$$dS=\mu S t + \sigma S dB,$$
where $B$ is a Brownian motion, for modeling. The historical prices are
$$\{S_i\}_{i=1}^N,$$
from which I calculate the log-returns ($N-1$ in total)
$$Z_i=\ln\frac{S_i}{S_{i-1}},$$
and the 1-day historical volatility as the standard deviation of the returns:
$$\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{Var\{Z_i\}}.$$

**Q1:** Let's say I want to forecast the prices $S(t)$ for 180 days. Should I take $\sigma$ in the SDE as the 1-day volatility $\hat{\sigma}$ or as $\sqrt{180}\hat{\sigma}$? I'd say that $\sigma=\hat{\sigma}$ as I'm modeling day by day, but is it correct?

**Q2:** How do I compute the drift $\hat{\mu}$ from the historical prices?  Is it simply
$$\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}Z_i,$$
and is it (the above formula) a *1-day drift*?

Comment: You may want to take into account weekends and holidays if you are forecasting for half of a year. A trading year is about 252 days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By looking at log returns, you are examing the stochastic process

$$
Q_t = \log S_t
$$

given by

$$
\begin{align}
dQ_t & = \left( \mu - \tfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right) dt + \sigma\, dB_t \\
& \equiv \alpha \,dt + \sigma\, dB_t
\end{align}
$$

where $\alpha=\mu-\tfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2$.

So far, everything is in continuous time. To interpret the SDE, you need to know how much time passes when $t$ increases by one unit. If the distance between $t=0$ and $t=1$ is one day, then $Q_{t+1}-Q_t$ is the daily log return, and $\mu$ is the daily drift. However, if the distance between $t=0$ and $t=1$ is one year, then $\mu$ is the annual drift.

Let's assume that one unit of $t$ is one day. Then defining $Z_i = Q_{i+1} - Q_i$ (which is equivalent to your definition of log returns) the formula

$$
\hat{\alpha} = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} Z_i
$$

gives the one-day drift for this process, and

$$
\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N-2} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} (Z_i - \hat{\alpha})^2
$$

gives the one-day variance (hence $\hat{\sigma}$ is the one-day standard deviation). To recover the estimator for the drift term $\mu$ you define

$$
\hat{\mu} = \hat{\alpha} + \tfrac{1}{2}\hat{\sigma}^2
$$

If you want the 180-day drift and standard deviation, you need

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\mu}_{180} & = 180\hat{\mu} \\
\hat{\sigma}_{180} & = \sqrt{180}\,\hat{\sigma}
\end{align}
$$

Purely as a point of notation, I would take your price observations to be $\{S_i\}_{i=0}^N$ so that you have $N+1$ price observations, and $N$ daily returns. It will simplify your formulas later.

Comment: What about the Ito component? shouldn't $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}Z_i}{N-1}$ be an estimate of $\mu - \sigma^2 / 2$

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct - I'll update the answer.

Comment: So, I should input $\hat{\mu}_{180}$ and $\hat{\sigma}_{180}$ as estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the SDE (eventually, I'll use the solution $S(t)$ to that equation); i.e., having an initial condition $S(0)$ I then just compute $S(180)$?

Comment: @corey979 That depends on how you are interpreting $t$ in your SDE. See my updates to the answer.

Comment: Yes, $t$ is measured in days. I found in [Mantegna & Stanley *An Introduction to Econophysics*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.452.605&rep=rep1&type=pdf), on p. 118, after Eq. 14.5, that $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are "per unit time", so the daily drift and volatility as the time unit is 1 day. And it makes more sense to make 2500\$ from the initial 1000\$ than an amount so huge that it causes an overflow on my computer.